# Reading mail spool in C

Tags: c, email

I am designing a program that will run on a mailserver.  It is intended to monitor email sent to a particular username and act on input received through the email messages.

My idea is to run this program from a cron job every X minutes, check for new email, act on the email if it's present, and delete the email.

Of course, I could easily open and read /var/spool/mail/username directly as a regular text file, then truncate the file once I've read through it.  But what's the proper way deal with the situation without stepping on sendmail? Another email might show up for that user either while I'm still reading the file or while I'm truncating it.

Comment: Have you considered procmail?

Comment: I'm voting to move this to serverfault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally what you're trying to do is better accomplished through server-side filtering as the mail arrives rather than trying to search through a mailbox every so often.  It's complex and if you get it wrong, you end up losing mail.

Instead, look to server side filtering like [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) or similar to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I had considered punting and using getmail, fetchmail or ?? to pick up the mail, then processing from there, but it seems like it shouldn't be necessary when the mail spool text file is sitting right there, a simple "fopen" away.

Comment: The way `procmail` works is that you get to filter the mail *before* it lands in the user's spool file. It sounds like exactly the tool you want for the job.

Comment: Ok, colour me convinced.  I just read the procmail webpage and it looks like it can even crank up my program when the email arrives, avoiding the wait that would be otherwise involved with a cron job.  So I guess that's two problems solved in one blow.